# Slow download / upload speed from AWS S3 to AWS EC2 in same region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm using AWS CLI to download big file from S3 bucket ( heroku db backup ) to my EC2 instance and upload big file ( about 110gb) to my AWS S3 bucket from my AWS EC2

Problem is when download ( from bucket that I don't own ) or upload to my bucket ( they are all in same region us-east-1 ) . Speed when download/upload start at about 60MB/s but decrease to 7-8MB/s after first 15gb even when I enable transfer acceleration .

So this is problem with AWS CLI config or my EC2 instance ( I'm testing with t2.micro ) ?Tks

Comment: The only network limitations imposed by AWS are related to the Instance Type. Take a look at the **Network Performance** column on [Amazon EC2 Instance Types - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). It should be faster if you choose a larger instance, or a family that supports higher Network Performance (eg T3 family).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tested my ec2 internet connection with speedtest. The download / upload speed near 1Gbps . enhanced networking is enabled but it can't keep speed when download / upload large file to s3

Comment: update: I switched to t3 ec2 with enhanced networking, and it work fine now

Comment: limiting the number of parallel uploads also worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of items you can try:

> - Use enhanced networking on the EC2 instance.
> - Use parallel workloads for the data transfer.
> - Customize the upload configurations on the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI).
> - Use an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) endpoint for Amazon S3.
> - Upgrade your EC2 instance type.
> - Use chunked transfers.

Read more here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-transfer-data-bucket-instance/

Comment: Do you have any idea why S3 download speed to my EC2 is so slow, I need to download database backup from heroku and it will generate S3 link for me .
This is my speedtest result so I don't think my EC2 instance internet connection is slow :( 

https://www.speedtest.net/result/c/c8e0c1ab-c9aa-4eb7-b8e9-6a32531c777b

Comment: Likely because you're using a t2.micro instance. Also turning on enhanced networking should increase the bandwidth.

Comment: update: I switched to t3 ec2 with enhanced networking, and it works fine now. tks